# How to export Eclipse project into Subversion

Tags: eclipse, svn

I have what may be considered a unique situation and then again may be not, at least it is unique to my experience.

On my local box I have a copy of an Eclipse project that is pointed directly to the code that sits on the Subversion server.  However, my development is done on the DEV server that sits on another DMZ due to regulatory requirements and because that is where the DATA resides.  In addition, the code base in DEV is NOT pointed to Subversion at all because again it sits on a different DMZ. (Please don’t ask me why.  That is just the way we’re setup here).

Consequently, I exported the eclipse project from the DEV server to my local box to try and overwrite the project that is pointed directly to the Subversion server.  However, when I try to import the project that I’ve extracted to a folder in my local box, in Eclipse by right clicking my local box's project name and the selecting IMPORT for existing Eclipse project, I get this message:

**Some projects cannot be imported because they already exist in the workspace**

Any suggestions/direction on what the best way to accomplish this would be very much appreciated.  Regards.

Comment: You are getting this warning because importing the exported codebase in eclipse from svn will lead to duplicacy of project names which eclipse workspace not allows. So either import in separate workspace or try to do overwriting outside eclipse

Answer (score 1):

The error is generated not because of subversion issues but because you are trying to import the same project into eclipse probably into the same workspace as your local project.

If you want to work with both versions your local and DEV, you will have to work in a new workspace for safest bet. You can rename, but renaming the project in the same workspace will lead to major confusion and unintended errors especially if you try to edit files with both projects open. 
Open eclipse in a new workspace e.g. Then import the project from DEV there into a clean workspace. This should give you the default setting for the project as it exists in DEV. if you delete the .project, etc files you will lose this info. If you need to work with your local project then you will need to switch workspaces back to your local project and vice versa

That the basic idea of workspaces.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the .classpath, .project, and .settings files recursively and try importing again.

Comment: Quick question for clarification.  Are you suggesting that I remove the .classpath, .project and .settings from the code base that I exported from the DEV server or from the project in subversion?  Thanks.

Comment: If you can, remove it from the subversion, else remove it from your WC and add them to your svn:ignore.

Comment: I backed up and then removed the .classpath and .project files from subversion, there was no .setting file) but when I tried the import through Eclipse again I got the same error message. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you importing the project as one with an existing name in your workspace?

Comment: Yes. It is the same project.  Should I just rename the existing project in SVN and then import?